# Eclipse Version differences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ganymede, helios

I currently use Eclipse Helios, and I need GWT Designer and GXT for my project. I also comfortably uses Aptana for Ruby which is also installed on Helios perfectly.

The database I need to use for my new project however would be IBM DB2, and I need to install IBM Data Studio, which seems to be not compatible with Helios. I tried to put Helios folder on IBM installer to let IBM Data studio install, but the installer said that I need some required minimum version. I noticed that IBM Data Studio uses Ganymede as its base.

So my questions are, if I revert back to Ganymede, what feature would I lose? Are all my tools run on Ganymede? Or better yet, can someone point me on how to update the package and install IBM data studio on Helios?

These are the requirement list for IBM Data Studio.

```
Some features and bundles of your existing Eclipse installation need to be upgraded with newer versions or are missing.  You must update your existing Eclipse using its Install/Update manager.  Use its "Help -> Software Updates -> Find and Install..." menu item to invoke its Install/Update manager.   Alternatively, you can download the features and bundles from eclipse.org.
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-4107w3121151A1A53" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-7C7iEQ7CYQCD_CZQ0Gsbd"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-7H7C7ACcNBHBBkHeGSMd" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-7F7iEC3BcMAB0APMvAsYW"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.apache.derby.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-77778eBmKDNOMgJvJ8Of7QBR" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-67q-AlRMQHHa6mIdwQGCK8DDI"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-7F47SFC7sRbrSZope9vW" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-7D8u0EB7sQSMRCr6ZcGW"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdbc.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-4-29oB56N5N7L6PAQ" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-37BEQ79oA55V5FBJ7CCH"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-548cAkF79P7UBMATEE" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-47U0_kE77g7MBZAWKQ"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-77078CcNBGKBZI_FcRd" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-67cEQ7BcMAB0AXKSEROS"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.data.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-640BgJ9DI9ZHVDdHL" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-37P-9oA55V5I8F_DFH"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddl.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-277078B03G8S_IMz00IwOmQz00Vl" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-27G-84B_tQF8HjTNKHDbOxHz00dZ"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddlgen.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-7A-2F7RZHLz-HvNlPz-Uk" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-777qEC3CYQCDACaNwGz-cY"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-7N7y7AFDrhoZFIFUNhpFwckfaS-S" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-7F9A-E8zTnlz-F0sj8WVDp1sU_lK"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.parsers.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-622BgJ9CR9XFcEWLP" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-57QEC3AgI99q9SHQ_MFN"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.results.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-4209oB57E5N8H9ICE" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-37HEC39oA55V5GAS6OCG"
  Feature "org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.sqlbuilder.feature_1.8.1.v20100618-79-3EVVFJoFsJcMz0Pe" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844-67q-BcMAB0AQJlBrZQ"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby_1.0.100.v200906020900" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905272100"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby.dbdefinition_1.0.2.v200906161815" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200904110060"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby.ui_1.0.3.v201007080903" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200903231723"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic_1.0.1.v200908130547" needs to be updated to version "1.0.900.v200905272045"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic.ui_1.0.1.v201004070709" needs to be updated to version "1.4.900.v200904300004"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.dbdefinition.genericJDBC_1.0.1.v200906161815" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.3.1.v201008030730" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_3.2.3.v201005281018" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design_3.3.1.v201008171206" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui_3.2.4.v201007150318" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile_3.1.1.v201001131420" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.ui_3.1.1.v201001131420" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile_3.2.4.v201007150318" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.template.ui_3.2.1.v201004090942" needs to be updated to version "3.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core_1.2.1.v201008120113" needs to be updated to version "1.4.900.v200905282304"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.dse_1.1.4.v201004270430" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.iseries_1.0.2.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.iseries.dbdefinition_1.0.3.v200906161800" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.iseries.ui_1.0.1.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905291747"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw_1.0.2.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201005211215" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905271128"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.ui_1.0.2.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.zseries_1.0.2.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.zseries.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905271128"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.zseries.ui_1.0.1.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905291747"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.informix_1.0.1.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905271859"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.informix.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905291333"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.informix.ui_1.0.2.v201005211230" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905060052"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle_1.0.0.v200908130544" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905271929"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.dbdefinition_1.0.101.v201004211630" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905071834"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.ui_1.0.2.v201005051303" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.dbdefinition_1.0.2.v201002130228" needs to be updated to version "1.4.900.v200904300004"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.derby_1.0.0.v201002161452" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql_1.0.4.v201002250945" needs to be updated to version "1.0.900.v200905142330"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.edit_1.0.1.v201002161452" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query_1.1.1.v201008100700" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905202345"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query.edit_1.0.0.v200906022249" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200903030235"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.xml.query_1.0.1.v201004291415" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200904230100"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.common.ui_1.0.0.v200906022302" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.data.core_1.2.0.v201005241300" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200906022030"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.data.ui_1.2.0.v201005250945" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200903312339"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.derby_1.0.0.v200906020900" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.generic_1.0.0.v200906020900" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.ddlgen.ui_1.0.1.v201002270530" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200906051811"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.debugger.core_1.0.1.v201005250945" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.editor.core_1.0.0.v201001150815" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql_1.0.2.v201004291415" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200904250115"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.lexer_1.0.1.v200906030654" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200904250115"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.xml.query_1.0.0.v200906022302" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905220200"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.plan_1.0.0.v200906022302" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result_1.1.0.v201005260930" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905291806"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.routineeditor_1.0.0.v201003161000" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200902280844"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlbuilder_1.0.3.v201009131745" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200903030240"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor_1.0.1.v201005130745" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905121950"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook_1.0.1.v201005250945" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200904272237"
  Bundle "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.tabledataeditor_1.0.1.v201005250945" needs to be updated to version "1.9.0.v200905081654"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as tool compatibility you need to check each tool you are concerned with individually.

Concerning this...

> So my question is, if I revert back to
>   Ganymede, what feature would I lose?

...I find [this site](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/10/15/eclipse-3-6-helios-new-and-noteworthy) helpful for collecting the "new and noteworthy" for each release. This link in particular has the Helios laid out, but also has a link to what's new in Galileo.

Comment: Thank you for the site.. That's helpful. It seems I would lose a lot when I downgrade to ganymede. The best option remains to integrate IBM Data Studio with Helios, or Galileo. As for those tools compatibility, I have checked those extensions, and I found that the all my extensions are already the newest version. But IBM Data Tools needs a "more" newer version. If I can update those files, that would be helpful..

Comment: er.. sorry.. it seems I misinterpreted extensions as tools.. I was meant to say that all my extensions are already the newest version. I have just checked that gwt designer to be compatible with 3.4, but aptana need 3.5. I use aptana for javascript and radrails, which is pretty much a loss to me.